# SQL- get XML tag name and value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a temp table .**The number of column and name of column of this table can be vary.Because this temp table is generate from another query**. mean it can be 3-15 . i get the XML from the temp table using below command:

```
DECLARE @XML XML 
SET @XML= (SELECT * FROM ##temp FOR XML PATH(''))
```

Example Output: `<Name>abc</Name><ID>3</ID><Address>100/8 NY</Address>`

Now i want the tag name and their corresponding value into a @variable ,say @StoreData.

Say `select @StoreDate` will print the below expected output
Expected Output:

Name='abc' and ID='3' and address='100/8 NY'

How i get it. Thanks in advance.
Note: i am using MS SQL version 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will meet your requirement...

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
        xr.value('fn:local-name(.)','varchar(50)') name, 
        xr.value('.','varchar(20)') val
    from @xml.nodes('//.') xq(xr)
    where xr.value('fn:local-name(.)','varchar(50)')<>''
)
    select STUFF(
        (select ' and ' + name + '='''+val+'''' from cte for xml path('')),1,4,'')
```

However, if you're trying to build up a sql filter string, I'd suggest using `sp_executesql` with parameters instead of building the SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this; Here is the working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6383)

**Your variable:**

```
DECLARE @XX XML = '<Name>abc</Name><ID>3</ID><Address>100/8 NY</Address>'
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 'Name = ''' + x.value('Name[1]','VARCHAR(100)') + ''' and ' +
       'ID = ''' + x.value('ID[1]','VARCHAR(100)') + ''' and ' + 
       'Address = ''' + x.value('Address[1]','VARCHAR(100)') + ''''
FROM @XX.nodes('/') MyXml(x)
```

**Output:**

```
Name = 'abc' and ID = '3' and Address = '100/8 NY'
```